# I am getting this error when trying to run 'rails s' I am trying to determine what needs to be done to resolve this

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I receive this error when running rails s below.

```
38f9d36f2320:rails-root ellimilt$ rails s
Traceback (most recent call last):
    19: from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
    18: from script/rails:6:in `require'
    17: from /Users/ellimilt/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/railties-6.0.3/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in `<top (required)>'
    16: from /Users/ellimilt/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/railties-6.0.3/lib/rails/command.rb:46:in `invoke'
    15: from /Users/ellimilt/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/railties-6.0.3/lib/rails/command/base.rb:69:in `perform'
    14: from /Users/ellimilt/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/thor-1.0.1/lib/thor.rb:392:in `dispatch'
    13: from /Users/ellimilt/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/thor-1.0.1/lib/thor/invocation.rb:127:in `invoke_command'
    12: from /Users/ellimilt/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/thor-1.0.1/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
    11: from /Users/ellimilt/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/railties-6.0.3/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:138:in `perform'
    10: from /Users/ellimilt/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/railties-6.0.3/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:138:in `tap'
     9: from /Users/ellimilt/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/railties-6.0.3/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:141:in `block in perform'
     8: from /Users/ellimilt/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/activesupport-6.0.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:324:in `require'
     7: from /Users/ellimilt/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/activesupport-6.0.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `load_dependency'
     6: from /Users/ellimilt/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/activesupport-6.0.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:324:in `block in require'
     5: from /Users/ellimilt/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/activesupport-6.0.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:324:in `require'
     4: from /Users/ellimilt/Documents/workspace/Pensieve/src/PensieveWebsite/rails-root/config/application.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
     3: from /Users/ellimilt/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/activesupport-6.0.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:324:in `require'
     2: from /Users/ellimilt/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/activesupport-6.0.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `load_dependency'
     1: from /Users/ellimilt/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/activesupport-6.0.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:324:in `block in require'
/Users/ellimilt/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/activesupport-6.0.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:324:in `require': cannot load such file -- action_mailer/railtie (LoadError)
```

Here's my gemfile

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'slim'
gem 'pry-rails'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'slim-rails'

# Gems used only for assets and not required
# in production environments by default.
group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails'
  gem 'coffee-rails'
  gem 'uglifier'
end
```

Answer (score 1):

```
cannot load such file -- action_mailer/railtie
```

ActionMailer is part of Rails. Your Gemfile is depending on things which use Rails, but it doesn't depend on Rails directly. Rails is no longer a monolith, and it is not guaranteed that loading `foo-rails` will also load all of Rails.

If we look at Gemfile.lock we can figure out how some bits of Rails have gotten installed as dependencies. For example, you have `railties` via `jquery-rails` (the exact dependencies and versions may vary).

```
    jquery-rails (4.3.5)
      rails-dom-testing (>= 1, < 3)
      railties (>= 4.2.0)
      thor (>= 0.14, < 2.0)
```

`railties` pulls in `activesupport`.

```
    railties (6.0.2.2)
      actionpack (= 6.0.2.2)
      activesupport (= 6.0.2.2)
      method_source
      rake (>= 0.8.7)
      thor (>= 0.20.3, < 2.0)
```

And that's the end of that dependency chain.

***It's important to directly depend on every gem you use directly*** and not to rely on some other gem dragging it in for you. By depending on `rails` (or [`rails-api`](https://github.com/rails-api/rails-api)) you guarantee to have all the pieces of Rails.

```
    rails (6.0.2.2)
      actioncable (= 6.0.2.2)
      actionmailbox (= 6.0.2.2)
      actionmailer (= 6.0.2.2)
      actionpack (= 6.0.2.2)
      actiontext (= 6.0.2.2)
      actionview (= 6.0.2.2)
      activejob (= 6.0.2.2)
      activemodel (= 6.0.2.2)
      activerecord (= 6.0.2.2)
      activestorage (= 6.0.2.2)
      activesupport (= 6.0.2.2)
      bundler (>= 1.3.0)
      railties (= 6.0.2.2)
      sprockets-rails (>= 2.0.0)
```

Specify rails and its version. This says to stay within Rails version 6.x.

```
gem 'rails', '~> 6.0'
```

Typically Rails takes care of this when you make a new Rails app with `rails new myapp`.

Comment: I would have said the same thing, if that's the gem file. But rails is installed somewhere, right? Because the error message shows the command is loading _some_ rail-ties. So that bit is a bit confusing.

Comment: @GarrettMotzner Again, Rails is no longer a monolith. You have a `rails` binary installed somewhere, use `which rails` to find out where. And you have SOME of its dependent gems like `railties` and `activesupport`, but you're missing `actionmailer`. Other gems are pulling in pieces of Rails. For example, if you look at `Gemfile.lock` you'll see that `jquery-rails` pulls in `railties`. `railties` pulls in `actionpack` and `activesupport`, but not the rest of Rails. If you're using Rails your project needs to depend directly on `rails`.